# Transversals Related to Circles and Spheres

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus

I was wondering if anyone could provide insight into whether the intersection of 3 circles (no interior) in R^2 intersecting at a single point would be transversal. My struggle in understanding some of this is that if we take two overlapping circles intersecting at two points in R^2, then clearly these are transversal; however, when we have a third circle intersect one of these two points, I'm not sure if the result is transversal (I'd need to show the tangent space of a point and the circle span R^2, but what would be the tangent space of a point?). Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A point is a $0$-dimensional manifold. Accordingly, its tangent space is a $0$-dimensional vector space (consisting only of the $0$ vector), so no proper submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$ can intersect transversally with a point.